# How to calculate upload and download frequency in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Now am getting the current network type. How to calculate UARFCN?
Which Api I have to use?

```
int netType = telephonyManager.getNetworkType();
switch (netType) {
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
        return "2G";
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
        return "3G";
    case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
        return "4G";
```